# Maya MentalRay nodes keep loading despite removed

Tags: nodes, maya

I have removed Maya mental ray plugin, however, there are times as I am opening a new scene, I am seeing the node `mib_amb_occlusion` (I believe it is a mental ray node) present in the Scene

Though I know I can either remove it manually or via the option - Optimize Scene, but is there any viable solutions to make sure that it will not loads it? Or do I need to do some settings in the Prefernces' file etc?

By the way, I have tried checking the directories that house the plugins and I am hardly seeing any that relates to Mental Ray (mayatomr etc..)

Comment: Maya does not remove unknown nodes, its perfectly valid to have nodes you don't know of. This makes it possible to have scenes which use features you don't have licenses to and still operate on  the stuff you have licenses to. Presumably once you load the license the nodes would resume working. No there's no option I'm aware of. PS: please check your default scene file if the node is present in this file then it will be present. Point being this node is not present by default even if I do have mr loaded.

Comment: @joojaa I did try out your method of opening the default scene/ importing of scene elements to check if the node is there or not. In fact I have tried several times and it does not seems to be there. In actual fact, the mentalray node just seems to pop out of nowhere and this at times, hampers when I am trying to do some rendering and due to the presence of `mib_amb_occlusion` node, the rendering fails and errors out. Thus perhaps what I really wanted to know is how did the `mib_amb_occlusion` node even come out in the first place?

Comment: There might be some script in your environment that automatically makes the node. In any case if the node is unused it shouldn't matter but then again if a script is doing this anything can happen. This can not be effectively remote debugged. Try unloading all plugins form plugin manager, run maya env into a script folder thats empty has no plugin paths etc. Then pray factory scripts haven't been tampered. **PS:** yes you can make a node thats not recognized. Also check that the node is not used by dome other plugin (its valid).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. Maya questions on Stack Overflow should be limited to scripting and programming problems